# R shiny selectinput with database values

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to fetch the values in the dropdown from database:-

```
Server.R


sqlOutput<- reactive({

  sqlInput<- paste("select distinct ASSET_CLASS from DUMMY_TABLE")

  dbGetQuery(con, sqlInput)
})  

UI.R

selectInput('pick_assetclass',label ='Asset Class',choices=sqlOutput(),selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE,width="450px"),
```

Could you please let me know the error in the code?

Error message:-

```
Error in lapply(obj, function(val) { : 
  could not find function "sqlOutput"
```

Thanks,
This is the edited code as per your valuable answers.
I see the column names in the dropdown alongwith the filtered values.
Could you let me know how to resolve it?

Server.R

```
sqlOutputAssetClass <- reactive({

      sqlInputAssetClass<- paste("select distinct ASSET_CLASS from DUMMY_TABLE",sep="")

    dbGetQuery(con, sqlInputAssetClass)
   })

    sqlOutputFeedSrcSys <- eventReactive(input$pick_assetclass,({

      sqlInputFeedSrcSys<- paste("select distinct FEED_SRC_SYS from DUMMY_TABLE where ASSET_CLASS=","'",input$pick_assetclass,"'",sep="")

      dbGetQuery(con,sqlInputFeedSrcSys)
    }) )        

   observe ({
    updateSelectInput(session,"pick_assetclass","ASSET CLASS",
                       choices = sqlOutputAssetClass()
     )
   })

   observe ({
    updateSelectInput(session,"pick_feedsrcsys","FEED SOURCE SYSTEM",
                       choices = sqlOutputFeedSrcSys()
     )
   })
```

UI.R

```
selectInput('pick_assetclass',label ='Asset Class',choices=NULL,selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE,width="450px"),
   selectInput('pick_feedsrcsys',label ='Feed Src Sys',choices=NULL,selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE,width="450px"),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi to do that you will need a observe or renderUI, I prefer observe so let's see:

```
sqlOutput<- reactive({

  sqlInput<- paste("select distinct ASSET_CLASS from DUMMY_TABLE")

  dbGetQuery(con, sqlInput)
})  

observe ({

updateSelectInput(session, "pick_assetclass",
                               choices = sqlOutput()
      )

})
```

Hope it helps. (You will need to add session to the function server like this)

```
shinyServer(

  function(input, output, session) {
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that in a shiny app, the `ui` function runs before the `server` function. This makes sense from a design standpoint because the `inputs` need to exist for R to make sense of reactive expressions in the `server` code, but it causes problems when the UI depends on variables generated in `server`.

The simplest solution is to replace your `selectInput` with a `uiOutput` and move the `selectInput` into a `renderUI` function in your server code:

UI:

```
uiOutput('ui_assetClass')
```

Server:

```
output$ui_assetClass <- renderUI({
    selectInput('pick_assetclass',
                label ='Asset Class',
                choices=sqlOutput(),
                selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE,width="450px"),
)}
```

EDIT: Your problem with the column names appearing in the list is likely due to `dbGetQuery` returning a named vector. Just strip the names with `unname` and it should work. This question deals with a similar problem: [Column Names in Dropdown R Shiny SelectInput from data base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49863312/column-names-in-dropdown-r-shiny-selectinput-from-data-base#49865771)

Comment: Thanks to both of you..they work great!..i am using updateSelectInput in my code..however there is a strange thing happening with the dropdowns - i see the column name in the filters too..updated the code in the main post for review.