# Column Names in Dropdown R Shiny SelectInput from data base

Tags: r, shiny

I am using the below code to populate the dropdown with database values:-

Server.R

```
sqlOutputAssetClass <- reactive({
    sqlInputAssetClass<- paste("select distinct ASSET_CLASS from DUMMY_TABLE",sep="")
    dbGetQuery(con, sqlInputAssetClass)
   })

sqlOutputFeedSrcSys <- eventReactive(input$pick_assetclass, {
    sqlInputFeedSrcSys<- paste("select distinct FEED_SRC_SYS from DUMMY_TABLE where ASSET_CLASS=",
                               "'",
                               input$pick_assetclass,"'",sep="")
    dbGetQuery(con,sqlInputFeedSrcSys)
    })        

observe ({
    updateSelectInput(session,"pick_assetclass","ASSET CLASS",
                      choices = sqlOutputAssetClass())
   })

observe ({
    updateSelectInput(session,"pick_feedsrcsys","FEED SOURCE SYSTEM",
                      choices = sqlOutputFeedSrcSys())
   })
```

UI.R

```
selectInput('pick_assetclass',label ='Asset Class',
            choices=NULL,selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE,width="450px"),

selectInput('pick_feedsrcsys',label ='Feed Src Sys',
            choices=NULL,selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE,width="450px"),
```

I see the dropdowns are filled with values but also the column names in the database table.
Another strange thing is that when there is just one value in the dropdown then the value doesn't display but the column name displays.

Could you please let me know how to resolve these issues?

[image]

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: Just convert `sqlOutputFeedSrcSys()` into an unnamed character vector containing the choices you want to display. You can use `browser()` inside `observe` to see which conversions are necessary.

Comment: thanks..could u please share a code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `?selectInput`:

> choices:  ... This can also be a named list whose elements are (either named or unnamed) lists or vectors. If this is the case, the outermost names will be used as the "optgroup" label for the elements in the respective sublist. This allows you to group and label similar choices. ...

So in your case, `dbGetQuery` is likely returning a named vector. Just run it through `unname` to strip those names before returning from `sqlOutputAssetClass` and the category names should go away:

```
sqlOutputAssetClass <- reactive({
    sqlInputAssetClass<- paste("select distinct ASSET_CLASS from DUMMY_TABLE",sep="")
    unname(dbGetQuery(con, sqlInputAssetClass))
   })
```

Comment: hi, i tried this approach.i am getting  c("FX", "CS", "AT", "FUTURES") in the dropdown.      'observe ({
    updateSelectInput(session,"pick_assetclass","ASSET CLASS",
                       choices = as.character(sqlOutputAssetClass()),selected = NULL
     )
   })'

Comment: Why did you put `as.character` around your call to `sqlOutputAssetClass` in the unformatted code in your above comment? I think that might be your problem

Comment: If the as.character is not there I get an error :-
Warning: Error in <Anonymous>: All sub-lists in "choices" must be named.

Comment: Did you look at the output of `sqlOutputAssetClass`? What is it returning? You want it to return an unnamed character vector.

Comment: could resolve it this way- observe ({
    updateSelectInput(session,"pick_assetclass","ASSET CLASS",
                      choices = unique(as.character(unlist(sqlOutputAssetClass()))),selected = NULL
     )
   })          It works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but an extended comment.

In order to see what values are passed to `updateSelectInput`, you can put a call to `browser()` just before the update like so

```
observe ({
  choices = sqlOutputAssetClass()
  browser()
  updateSelectInput(session,"pick_assetclass","ASSET CLASS",
                   choices = sqlOutputAssetClass()
  )
})
```

this will open an interactive console where you can print your choices as well as all other inputs/reactives and see which changes are necessary to convert it to a "bare" character sting without labels, attributes or names. This console will block the console until you click "next" and will be reopened whenever the `observe` block is run.

The object you eventually want to pass to the update function should look like this

```
choices <- c("FX", "CS", "AT", "FUTURES")
```